# Regular Expressions: Removing this [##### : #####] from a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to remove this `[###:###]` from the beginning of a string `[###:###]other random text` using regex substitution.

I've tried:

```
line = '[123:456]othertext'
print re.sub(r'^[\d*:\d*],'',line)
```

But this leaves the brackets behind: `'[]othertext'`

The issue here is that brackets traditionally indicate a regex capture group. So I then attempted to ignore them with the escape key `\\`:

```
line = '[123:456]othertext'
print re.sub(r'^\\[\d*:\d*\\],'',line)
```

And this showed no change to the string: `'[123:456]othertext'`

How do I correctly format the regex expression?

Comment: Single backslashes should be used in raw string literals.

Comment: What is wrong with `line.rpartition(']')[-1]`?

Comment: @user3100115 This would work for the example I provided, but many of the strings I'm splitting use brackets at both the beginning and end. In this case the precise answer succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single backslashes should be used in raw string literals to escape special regex metacharacters and shorthand character classes.

Use

```
import re
line = '[123:456]othertext'
print re.sub(r'^\[\d*:\d*\]','',line)
#               ^        ^
# => othertext
```

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/9MPpvH)